# Spring Kafka Template send with retry based on different cases

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka's KafkaTemplate for sending message using the async way and doing proper error handing using callback.

Also, I have configured the Kafka producer to have maximum of retries (MAX_INTEGER).

However there maybe some errors which is related with avro serialization, but for those retry wouldn't help. So how can I escape those error without retries but for other broker related issues I want to do retry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialization exception will occur before the message is sent, so the `retries` property is irrelevant in that case; it only applies when the message is actually sent.

Comment: Hi, I am checking the `KafkaProducer` doc of Kafka and the asyc `send` method does throw `SerializationException`. So which means serialization happens as part of send. Do I miss something here? NB: I am using Kafka avro and the schema needs to be checked against schema registry.

Comment: Yes, it's done while sending but since the creation of the actual data to send fails, nothing is actually sent to the broker - hence `retries` won't kick in. That property is all about getting the serialized data to the broker reliably after it is successfully serialized, but, in this case, there is no serialized data because serialization failed.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Just looked at the source code and only exceptions are extend from `RetriableException` could be retried. This retry behaviour is not the same as consumer with deserialization.